# Video Streaming not working over internet or local network

Tags: java, applet, rtp, jmf

I'm working on a project that needs to implement live video streaming from webcam on server into applet on remote client.

I have a code for capturing live stream from webcam through JMF on server & deploy streaming on rtp & an applet that receive streaming from the rtp address then play it into it.

But the problem that it's only working within my own pc (server) & doesn't work over local network (it loads applet but doesn't run the video player).

Server Code:

```
public class Streaming_Server {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private static String PORT = "10000";
    private static InetAddress addr;
    static final Format[] FORMATS = { new VideoFormat("rgb") };
    static final ContentDescriptor CONTENT_DESCRIPTOR = new ContentDescriptor("raw.rtp");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoDataSourceException, NoProcessorException, CannotRealizeException, NoDataSinkException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try
        {
            addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String ipAddr = addr.getHostAddress();
            String hostname = addr.getHostName();
            System.out.println("Your IP is " + ipAddr);
            System.out.println("Your Host Name is " + hostname);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e){}


        CaptureDeviceInfo webcamInfooo = new CaptureDeviceInfo("Camera", new MediaLocator("vfw://0"), null);
        MediaLocator camDeviceMediaLocator = webcamInfooo.getLocator();
        DataSource source = Manager.createDataSource(camDeviceMediaLocator);
        Processor mediaProcessor = Manager.createRealizedProcessor(new ProcessorModel(source, FORMATS, CONTENT_DESCRIPTOR));
        //MediaLocator outputMediaLocator = new MediaLocator("rtp://" + addr.getHostAddress() + ":" + PORT + "/video");
        MediaLocator outputMediaLocator = new MediaLocator("rtp://192.168.1.4:20000/video");
        DataSink dataSink = Manager.createDataSink(mediaProcessor.getDataOutput(), outputMediaLocator);

        mediaProcessor.start();
        dataSink.open();
        dataSink.start();
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
public class Streaming_Client extends Applet implements ControllerListener {

    /**
     * Initialization method that will be called after the applet is loaded into
     * the browser.
     */
    Player player = null;
    private MediaLocator mediaLocator;
    private static String PORT = "10000";
    private static InetAddress addr;

    public void init() {
        // TODO start asynchronous download of heavy resources
        //mediaLocator = new MediaLocator("rtp:/192.168.1.4:10000/video");
        mediaLocator = new MediaLocator("rtp:/192.168.1.4:20000/video");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        try {
            player = Manager.createPlayer(mediaLocator);
            player.addControllerListener(this);
        } catch (IOException | NoPlayerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Streaming_Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        player.start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        player.stop();
        player.deallocate();
    }

    public void destroy(){
        player.close();
    }
    // TODO overwrite start(), stop() and destroy() methods

    @Override
    public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent ce) {
        if ((ce instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent))
        {
        Component comp;
        if ((comp = this.player.getVisualComponent()) != null)
            add("Center", comp);
        if ((comp = this.player.getControlPanelComponent()) != null)
            add("South", comp);
        validate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is open and copy/paste the output.  I guess some 'Access' related exception will be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, i found that MediaLocator in server takes the **Destination IP** not the source one.

It's an annoying thing as you must know where you are streaming.

So, after this edit..

```
CaptureDeviceInfo webcamInfooo = new CaptureDeviceInfo("Camera", new MediaLocator("vfw://0"), null);
MediaLocator camDeviceMediaLocator = webcamInfooo.getLocator();
DataSource source = Manager.createDataSource(camDeviceMediaLocator);
Processor mediaProcessor = Manager.createRealizedProcessor(new ProcessorModel(source, FORMATS, CONTENT_DESCRIPTOR));
//MediaLocator outputMediaLocator = new MediaLocator("rtp://" + addr.getHostAddress() + ":" + PORT + "/video");
MediaLocator outputMediaLocator = new MediaLocator("rtp://192.168.1.6:20000/video");
DataSink dataSink = Manager.createDataSink(mediaProcessor.getDataOutput(), outputMediaLocator);
```

i can stream live video capturing from 192.168.1.4 to 192.168.1.6 over **Intranet** only.

but i can't find till now how to stream over internet as i must assign remote pc ip.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid assigning destination ip as i want to publish the applet?